# load magento email template

Tags: email, magento, templates

I'm using my own code to send out SMS's to the customers at the same time as the emails go out.  I do this by getting the email template code with

```
$code = $this->getTemplateCode();
```

and then trying to load the corresponding SMS template with

```
$sms = $this->loadByCode('sms_'.$code)->getTemplateText();
```

I then check if `$sms` is empty before proceeding to send the text, meaning that I can add or remove connected SMS templates at will. The problem I'm having is that I sometimes, when there is no connected "sms_*" template, I get the full email sent out as the SMS instead of no text being sent.

I've debugged the code by sending out the template it tries to load as the actual SMS, and received "sms_creditmemo", but when I instead load it with the method above and do a `var_dump($sms); exit;`it shows me that it loaded the template "creditmemo_invoice" which is the email template I use instead of "creditmemo" when the payment method is detected. I make sure to use the original template string in `$code` (used to load SMS template) no matter the payment method.

Now my question would be how this can even be possible, does the loadByCode take best matching template or is there some other more serious bug I've missed, maybe there's better ways to load in the templates and make correct checks to see if they even exist?

Comment: I noticed now that this only happens when I override the original email template. It seems like the `getTemplateText()`-part is taking the overridden email template from the object data when there is something there, and on "normal" email templates this is empty since it's all in origData?  Perhaps I should try and find a way to make a new instance for the SMS template loading, or make sure to empty the object template data....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by checking if the correct email template gets loaded with

```
if ($this->loadByCode($template)->getTemplateCode() == $template)
```